# Using Tailwind vs. BEM

Tags: css, sass, frameworks

I know the title might be a little off but you know what I mean :)

I'm a pure front-end developer and I might be heading into a React project where other developers that are more back-end than me wanna use the CSS framework Tailwind (https://tailwindcss.com).

I have been using BEM with some modifications for a couple of years now and really like it. I can not see why I would wanna use something like Tailwind when I have more freedom and is more effective with BEM?

Am I right when I think Tailwind is great for back-enders who needs to do front-end, but not dedicated front-end developers?

Looking forward to your opinions!

Comment: You can completely use BEM and Tailwind at the same time as a Frontend developer

Answer (score 5):

Your question can be rephrased like this **Using predefined css** VS **writing your own css**

People use CSS Framework( [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/what-is-tailwind/), Bootstrap, Foundation, Bulma,... etc) for Rapid UI Development, where as [BEM](https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/bem_by_example) is just a CSS Naming Convention that can be used with any of the Frameworks above.

It has nothing to do with Backend or Frontend, hope it answers your question.